# PHPExcel Make Last row bold

Tags: php, excel, laravel

This is how we can make the First row text as bold:-

```
$sheet->getStyle('A1:'.$sheet->getHighestColumn().'1')->getFont()->setBold(true);
```

**But how can we make the Last row of the sheet as bold?**

Comment: What have you tried so far? We use to keep track of the amount of rows we insert and therefore know where the last row is.

Comment: @4ice has already answered what I was looking for. See the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `$sheet->getHighestRow()` should be possible to use. So with your example above, you should be able to write:

```
$sheet->getStyle('A' . $sheet->getHighestRow() . ':'.$sheet->getHighestColumn().$sheet->getHighestRow())->getFont()->setBold(true);
```